# C#/Unity Lives goes to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    do{
    if(other.transform.tag == "Player"){ //checking to see who bumps into it(PlayerShip)
        Vector3 currentPos = transform.position; //grabbing the position of player
        string currentTag = transform.tag; //also grabbing it's tag
        if(currentTag == "a_large"){//based on which asteroid is hit, it does something different
                GameController.lives1--;

        }
        else if(currentTag == "a_medium"){
                GameController.lives1--;
        }
        else if(currentTag == "a_small"){
                GameController.lives1--;

        }

    }
    }
    while(GameController.lives1 > 0);
```

This is my script. I did the same thing for Score (except it increments, and no do while loop) and it works fine. For some reason though when my collider other with tag "Player" hits asteroid with tag 'a_large' the 'int lives1' goes to 0. I think my syntax is off just trying to get some feedback at how I can fix this remedy.

Comment: _"when my collider other with tag "Player" hits asteroid with tag 'a_large' the 'int lives1' goes to 0"_ - that does seem like what you would want to happen, given `lives1` was `1` before. What do you initialize it to? I do not know how Unity works though, but you do not seem to change `transform`'s value in the loop, which would mean it would keep looping until it hits `0`.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Due to your `do{ }while()`, your `lives1` can equal `1`, then when it hits `a_large`, the `1` gets decremented to `0`.

Comment: wait, excuse my poor programming, I am a student. I'm confused on what you mean though. My value for lives1 (located in my GameController class) is set to 3. When the game starts the lives1 is 3, and then when it collides with asteroid it goes to 1. I may be wrong, am I saying somewhere in here that lives1 is 1? I do not see it, but then again I am a student. It may be due to my do-while loop, I thought what I was doing with that is making it so lives can no be less than 0.

Comment: Is there anything else inside this loop?

Comment: The first time this runs, it will run until GameController.lives1 == 0.

Comment: It must be because of the do-while loop, once I took that off it decrements normally. I guess my new question is how to create a loop for this that does not let lives1 go below 0. I would also need to create a bool value and set it to true when lives1 hit 0, so that game over is called if that value is true.

Comment: You don't need a loop to check true or false. just use an `if` to prevent the value from going below 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to fully clarify what was going wrong:

You were using a loop to prevent the value of `lives1` from getting to `0`. Instead of what you expected, you were immediately decrementing `lives1` to `0`. Why?

When your code entered the loop, `currentTag == "a_large"` was `true`. Note that the `currentTag` is never updated in your loop.

On the first iteration, the `currentTag` still was `a_large`, so `lives1` was decremented. The second iteration, the  `currentTag` was still `a_large`, so another decrement. Repeat until you finally hit your break condition of the loop, which was `lives1 <= 0`.

As @dwerner said, just use an `if( lives1 == 0 )` statement to check for `lives1` being `0`.